# Remove a certain string (hint) from SQL code in oracle

Tags: oracle, replace, regexp-replace

I have a string (clob) that contains SQL query with hints, i need to remove those hints from the sql code.

so this:

```
select 
/*+ ALL_ROWS */ 
/* 2014-12-08 08:26:40.533 -6e99e394:14a2a127782:-466(TXN_ID:-1) */ 
ID, ORIGIN_TICKET_ID, LIFECYCLE_STATUS ...
```

should looks like:

```
select ID, ORIGIN_TICKET_ID, LIFECYCLE_STATUS ...
```

I tried to play with replace and REGEXP_REPLACE but with no luck so far.

Comment: Please provide the statements, that failed to deliver the expected result.

Comment: You seem to want to remove ordinary comments as well - not just hints. If so: Are all of them coming immediately after the `SELECT `? Are all these statements stored as single lines, or might they have line breaks? Which version of Oracle?

Comment: Basically everything between /* and */ should be removed (hints), no need to handle comments, oracle is v11.2.0.2

Comment: An example would be:
SELECT REPLACE(main.c,'/\*%\*/') FROM MAIN;

but the % doesn't do the job and i cant seem to find something equivalent to do that.

Comment: A hint is a comment immediately following the `SELECT` with an additional plus sign after the comments openening `/*`. In your example, the substring holding the date information is an ordinary comment, not a hint.

Comment: Yes i need to remove this also, the hint the comment, as i said anything in between /* and */ (comment or hint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to handle the CLOB…

Something along

```
SELECT 'SELECT '
  || TRIM(SUBSTR(str, LENGTH(str) - INSTR(REVERSE(str), '/*') + 2)) cleanedStatement
FROM
  (SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(main.c, 4000, 1) str FROM Main
  );
```

should provide the requested as long as the comments (hints or not) are all placed at the statements' start.

Comment: The main.c column is a clob and the reverse doesnt work on that:

Comment: The main.c column is a clob, the reverse function doesnt work on it:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes
i will try to work along the lines of your example and try to find a workaround, but if you have any other idea that would be nice, Thanks !

Comment: Noticed the CLOB too late for my original suggestion. Started to adjust accordingly. Might your statements be longer than 4,000 characters?